# Display n number of tables dynamically using split() function using shiny R(QUESTION HAS BEEN SOLVED THANK YOU)

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have made an app where a user uploads a data and then this data is split() according to a column. For example lets say i am doing a split on Iris dataset. I might use split(iris, iris$Species). This will give me 3 datasets (see below). Now I want these three datasets to show up dynamically in three tables.

Because the data uploaded by the user will be different each time, the split will give different number of tables. Iris gave 3 datasets but we can get any number of table based on the data. Now I want to display these 3 datasets to be shown in 3 tables in shiny dynamically. If I had 4 datasets due to split(), then 4 tables should show up dynamically.

I have tried to code something but it gives me the same table 3 times. It does not give me 3 different tables.

```
$setosa
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa


$versicolor
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
52           6.4         3.2          4.5         1.5 versicolor
53           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
54           5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
55           6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
56           5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor



$virginica
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5 virginica
102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1 virginica
104          6.3         2.9          5.6         1.8 virginica
105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2 virginica
106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1 virginica
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code a bit by creating a reactive expression that splits the dataset, is not really needed (using just iris dataset) but it will come in handy when user inputs are added.

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
data(iris)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
    #instead  of iris$Species an input$... can be passed
    Splitdfs <- reactive({split(iris, iris$Species)}) 
    
    output$data <- renderUI({
        
        tables <- map(Splitdfs() , ~{
            renderDataTable({.x})
        })
        mainPanel(tables)
        
    })
    
}



ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel(title = h4("Iris Dataset", align="center")),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),   
        uiOutput("data") #the ui will contain all the split tables.
    ))

#run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>